# Magento2 product view page is giving Uncaught TypeError: settings.$elementF.fotorama is not a function in gallery.js:297

Tags: jquery, magento, magento2

In my Magento 2 project, Fotoroma is not working fine. It is giving error like the following:

> gallery.js:297 Uncaught TypeError: settings.$elementF.fotorama is not a function

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Can you please provide your code so that we can help you?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/265842/typeerror-settings-elementf-fotorama-is-not-a-function this may help you

Comment: I used that solution but it didn't solved my issue

Comment: I tried to use this solution, but still not working. Did you solve issue?